# Inheritance division

Tags: sunni, hanafi, inheritance

I've been told that if someone dies, their assets MUST be divided correctly between the heirs asap based on Islamically outlined division percentages, otherwise the person(s) stopping the correct division (or stopping the division of the assets all together) of the assets are committing a major sin.

Is this true?

I would appreciate views from the sunni > hanafi > deobandi view.

Answer (score 1):

Assalam O Alaikum  
This is right. When someone (Muslim) dies, his/her family/relative must share his/her remaining in all of the relatives according to the Islam's teachings. 
1. When a Muslim dies, his/her remaining supposed to be shared equally to his direct relatives first (daughters, sons, brothers, sisters, etc. ) 
 
2. After 1st relatives, his/her remaining are must be divided equally in his/her relatives (male and female). But this must be done after sharing remainings into 1st relatives. 
3. If a person didn't left with any relatives then his/her property must be [Escheat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escheat) to the government treasury. 
 
There are a lot of other points that must be noted when we talk about distribution of inheritance. Like, only the relatives with direct blood relationship are entitled to inherit, it means only real son will have the right of getting his part, but the adopted one won't be entitle for inheritance. 
 
You can get brief knowledge about distribution of Inheritance in this article: [Islamic inheritance jurisprudence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_inheritance_jurisprudence)

Comment: _share his/her remaining in all of the relatives_, _remaining supposed to be shared equally to his direct relatives_, _remaining are must be divided equally in his/her relatives_ --- all these claims are so outrageously wrong. I suggest you refrain from giving fatwas.